# Changing Java base image considerations

Tags: java, docker

I have about 10 Spring boot Microservices which currently use the below base image:

https://hub.docker.com/r/fabric8/java-centos-openjdk11-jre

I've been asked to move to Alpine Linux or the Red Hat RHEL image. When moving to a different base image do I need to be worried about something breaking in my Java implementations? Or given that I would be moving to an image that has Java baked in, can I be fairly confident that things will just work?

I guess what I'm asking is what are the different considerations (besides licensing) i need to evaluate when I move to a different base image.

Comment: If you use a prepackaged java and don’t bring your own native library (very rare) you should be fine.  Just run your usual test suite

Comment: "*When moving to a different base image do I need to be worried about something breaking in my Java implementations?*" - Not the implementation, but it might be that commands we used in a previous base image are not present in the new base image. We should keep this in mind. For example, I used the [google distroless java image](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/distroless/global/java) some time back as a base image. In the base image, we do not have access to commands like `mkdir`, so we cannot create new directories from within the container, but have to `COPY` them from the host.